# Microsoft Edge Touch (hold) Feedback

Tags: touch, contextmenu, microsoft-edge

I am developing a touch application on Edge with my own touch interaction. One thing I want to get rid of is the long-touch (hold) feedback from the browser. Before, there was a context menu pops out after I hold my finger on the screen for a while, which I have successfully disabled. But there is still a annoying rectangle appears when I lift my finger off the screen, presumably a touch feedback, which i would like to disable but have no clue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, you could clear the outline on focus:

```
.btn:focus {
  /* The outline parameter surpresses the border color / outline when focused */
  outline: 0;
}
```

From https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/touch/ There are other possible situations you might want to cover for other browsers, but this should get rid of the button's default outline on touch events in Edge.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work... My guess is the long-touch event for activating contextual menu is not bound to any buttons.

Comment: Are there any hover styles for the buttons?  Those behave like focus in touch-only environments. I can only test on a desktop (emulating windows phone) so I'm not able to test this.  Are you using any templates/frameworks that might be adding a style rule? For example: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18650

Comment: i feel it's a browser thing rather than javascript. I tried it in chrome and didnt' see any of those. Also in the setting of windows, you can turn off the touch feedback, which will get rid of the little tail of touch input. The outline became smaller but still visible..